# Как отобразить зеркально текст для арабского языка, xml?

Tags: android, xml

[image]
Хочу для арабских стран зеркально отобразить текст. Но разобраться в этом (на примере ресурса https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html?linkId=15420153) не хватает ума. Может что еще посоветуете?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="88dp"
android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layoutDirection="locale"
android:paddingEnd="24dp"
android:text="@string/item_name"
android:textDirection="locale">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
android:hint="@string/item_name"
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
android:layoutDirection="locale"
android:maxLength="64"
android:maxLines="1"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:textDirection="locale" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: арабский текст вроде по умолчанию встает с правой стороны, нет?

Comment: У меня проблема с EditText. На скрине ItemName не стал на место, а вот ниже TextView и спиннер ок.

Comment: а вы вставьте сам арабский `مساء الخير`

Comment: у меня пока нет перевода, но если писать на арабском, такая картина получается. Хотя мне нужно, чтобы item name было справа [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xma0DxIet5eTLm9t_r7F_XAYzwmA_K7T]

Comment: то есть `item name` должен быть справа и выглядеть вот так `eman meti` ?

Comment: должен быть справа подобно Category

Comment: `зеркально` сбивает с толку.